# Stability of diaminocyclohexa-2,4-dienyl cations

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

I am facing trouble in the following question

> What is the order of stability of these compounds
>   [image]

In my view the stability must be greater for that compound which is able to disperse the positive charge most effectively. For that reason, 4,6-diaminocyclohexa-2,4-dien-1-ylium (*R*) should be most stable because the $\ce{-NH2}$ is ortho and para in that. The next most stable should be 2,5-diaminocyclohexa-2,4-dien-1-ylium (*Q*) followed by 3,5-diaminocyclohexa-2,4-dien-1-ylium (*P*). However the answer key gives it to be (*P*) > (*Q*) > (*R*). I couldn't understand where I am making mistake.

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions just like this one.  The lesson to be learned is that you need to draw out all of the resonance structures for each ion.  Then you can make arguments about their relative stability.

Comment: Maybe we really should start marking your questions as dupes …

Comment: Hint: You do not have an aromatic system in any of the three structures. I assume you thought you had because you used *ortho* and *para*.

Comment: @Jan I am aware of the Huckel's rule.I used ortho and para to denote positions relative to the carbocation.

Comment: @aniline It’s not even about Hückel’s rule which only relates to the number of electrons. You don’t even have a conjugated system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea in solving such questions should be to draw out the resonance structures as suggested by @ron

[image]

It is clear from the picture above that $P)$ has maximum resonance structures followed by $Q)$ and then $R)$ .Same
 is the order of their stability.

Comment: Now, you're on the right track, but note that there is 1 more resonance structure that you can draw for both P and Q.